# how to get a span text with xpath in php

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

HTML:

```
<div class="span9" bis_skin_checked="1">
<span id="lbl_aracmarka" style="color:#003366;font-size:Medium;">CITROEN</span></div>
```

PHP:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($response);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->query('//*[@id="lbl_aracmarka"]/following-sibling::text()')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I have such a piece of code, I want to extract the value of `citroen`, how can I do it? Current code gives back:

> **Warning**: Attempt to read property `nodeValue` on null in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/Indexes/x.php** on line **84**

Answer (score 0):

`CITROEN` is not in the element you are targeting so `following-sibling` is incorrect.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml('<div class="span9" bis_skin_checked="1">
<span id="lbl_aracmarka" style="color:#003366;font-size:Medium;">CITROEN</span></div>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query('//*[@id="lbl_aracmarka"]/text()') as $t){
    echo $t->nodeValue;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Q3L9V

You also can do it without the `foreach`, same logic you had:

```
echo $xpath->query('//*[@id="lbl_aracmarka"]/text()')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```